# What kind of Visa is required to work in Academia in Japan?

Tags: job-search, visa, japan

As from title. What kind of visa class do I have to apply for, in order to work as an academic in Japan ?

Comment: Generally the institution who hires you will prepare the required documents and process the application. If you come to Japan to hunt a job then you must apply for a temporary (tourist) visa that only allows you to stay in 90 days. But you might be waived for a tourist visa as you are a citizen who does not need a visa to enter Japan.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This](http://www.mofa.go.jp/j_info/visit/visa/process/long.html) might help or [this.](http://www.mofa.go.jp/j_info/visit/visa/long/visa1.html) Here is the crux of the information:

The period of stay is quoted as 3 years/1 year with the following documents needed:

```
Passport
One visa application form (nationals of Russia or NIS countries need to submit two visa application forms)
One photograph (nationals of Russia or NIS countries need to submit two photographs)
Certificate of Eligibility (Note) - the original and one copy
```

This visa applied for **Long-term stay** for the following occupations:

Working visa: professor, artist, religious activities, journalist, investor/business manager, legal/accounting services, medical services, researcher, instructor, engineer, specialist in humanities/International Services

The algorithm for obtaining the visa is given on [the first link I added](http://www.mofa.go.jp/j_info/visit/visa/process/long.html).
[image: Algorithm]

Answer (score 1):

In 2018 I worked there as an unpaid intern at the Tokyo University. I had the "cultural activity visa".